# jquery this animate this element without id

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML code I have a div. This div includes some warnings to the users. Warnings are wrapped inside div elements with no ID. If user clicks on close button, it should remove the warning div.

```
<div id="alarmbox" align="center">
      <div>this is warning 1<button onclick="remove_div_of_this_button(this);">x</button></div>
      <div>this is warning 2<button onclick="remove_div_of_this_button(this);">x</button></div>
</div>
```

and this is my JS code:

```
function remove_div_of_this_button(thisbutton)
{
    thisbutton.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(thisbutton.parentNode);
}
```

It works fine. However, removing an element is better to be animated instead of sudden remove. If I want to manipulate JS only, how to remove the div with jquery? Is it possible to identify `thisbutton` in jquery since $(thisbutton) should not work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate out js from your html and use click event with jquery.

With **[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)**

```
$(function(){
    $('#alarmbox button').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('div').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46dCW/)

Or try **[slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)**

#### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/mn8Qe/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe?

```
function remove_div_of_this_button(thisbutton)
{
    $(thisbutton).parent().fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: `
function remove_div_of_this_button(thisbutton)
{
    thisbutton.parentNode.parentNode.fadeOut(function() {
        $(thisbutton.parentNode).remove();
    });
}`

did not work

Comment: I updated that code right after I posted it, forgot to wrap in jquery.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).parentNode is undefined